# How to remove washroom tile color from eyeglasses lens?

Tags: cleaning, eyeglasses

A number of months ago, my eyeglasses fell onto a washroom tile. Now, due to the impact, some tile color which is white got onto my eyeglasses on the right lens. Some of the color came off. However, I want to get all of the tile color off. Palmolive dish soap is the only dish soap I have on hand to use and the eyeglasses cleaning solution did not make a difference. The lens are transition lens with scratch prevention coating on them. How to effectively remove the scratch-free lenses tile color from the lens without scratching the lens?

My home has soft water. That comes from a deep well. So, the water is softer than city tap water. Also, my eyeglasses are less than 2 years old. The color marks are not scratch marks because the tile color has faded in areas of the tiles over time. In the past, any fall of my eyeglasses if ever my eyeglasses fall onto the floor has never made a scratch on them. Thus, a scratch can be ruled out since most of the tile color came off upon washing my eyeglasses right after they fell onto the tile.

Comment: I think the bigger question would be how to remove the discolouration without removing the scratch-resistant coating from the lens.

Comment: How sure are you that the colour came from the tile, and is not actual damage to the lens? Generally **tiles are glazed** and do not have "colour that comes off." Do not clean the lenses with anything except what is recommended for cleaning scratch-proof lenses. They aren't actually scratch-proof to everything you inflict on them: it is a coating that only gives *some* protection.

Comment: ... against everyday activities. OTOH if you gouge it with a carpenter's chisel, it ain't going to resist that. Be realistic.

Comment: Do you really mean tile colour?  If the tile's glaze has come onto your glasses then you would see the damage on the tile.  Otherwise, do you have grout on you glasses?  That could be removed with the right solvent.

Comment: The white marks are slowly coming off of my eyeglasses where the localized mark lines are on the right lens. On the tile where the eyeglasses fell onto the tile surface, the white color is gone where the eyeglasses fell. Also, the white markings mostly came off of my eyeglasses when I immediately washed them from the right lens. I mainly clean my eyeglasses with dish soap. Other than that, use lens cleaning solution from where I bought my eyeglasses. In the washroom, the tiles are not glazed.

Comment: Hi, NaderH. Welcome to Lifehacks. I am highly skeptical of your premise. Rather than dwell on that, I encourage to bring your spectacles to an optometrist (where you got them would be ideal) who knows the product and has the knowledge, experience, and proper instrumentation to assess the kind of damage you describe. As well, a dispensing optometrist is in the best position to remedy the damage. I might be wrong; but, I'm never in doubt. Good luck.

Comment: I managed to start removing the white color from my glasses on the right lens. Over the past week, I have seen a gradual but slow improvement of the progress in the reduction of the marking's color. The whiteness is fading away. What I am doing is deep soaking the right lens in dish soak combined with water and then washing my gradually improving reduction of the white marking on the right lens when I wash my eyeglasses with dish soap. While the process is slow, it is working.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use chemicals, just repeated, **gentle** rubbing with a soft cloth made specifically for lens cleaning, possibly moistened, or not. This might remove some of the lens coating, or not, but should not affect lens clarity. I've used milk of magnesia as a very mild abrasive for plastic polishing, bu that likely would remove lens coating, too.

There are also glass polishes used by lens and telescope makers such as [cerium oxide](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=telescope%20mirror%20polish), which certainly would remove the stain, and the lens coating, and possibly a bit of the lens surface... but in severe case, that may be the only answer.